# Gas limit errors when deploying Greeter example contract on Remix

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

First time newbie eth contract question.   I'm using remix to compile the ethereum.com greeter example.  I'm having problems with the gas when I deploy the contract.

if I specify :

```
gas: eth.getBlock(eth.defaultBlock).gasLimit -1
```

I get

```
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

But if I bump it up to

```
gas: eth.getBlock(eth.defaultBlock).gasLimit +1
```

ask expected, I get

```
Error: exceeds block gas limit
```

my test balance is 22905390000000000, way over the gas limit.  I'm clearly not understanding something here.

I've gutted my code, this is the contract in its entirety:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract greeter {
    /* main function */
    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return "greeting" ;
    } 
}
```

When I submit this contract I get the error "Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount"

Update:  I printed out my eth.getBalance() before and after sending the contract.   I still get the error "couldn't be stored" but I notice that my balance is going down by my gas*gasPrice.

Comment: Sometimes you can get errors completely unrelated to the real reason why this failed during deployment. Double-check the rest of your code if you're completely sure that you are sending the right amount of gas. Also, try to tweak the gas sent more.

Comment: I've gutted my code to a single function that returns a static string.  The gas estimate is about 70000, I upped that to 80000 and I'm getting the error:  Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Answer (score 1):

In your Genesis.json file check the gas limit value if it was less, increase it to 2,10,000. In ethereum for sending transaction, it requires minimum 21,000 gas units.